# Arrangement of elements in html

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is possible to achieve this structure using html + css ?

But instead of having that vertical space between orange blocks I want to be one in the top of another.

I have used flex and grid but not really succeed so far  :(

**[jsfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/3uxcmL02/1/)**

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.big {
  width: calc(60% - 22px);
  padding: 10px;
  background: lime;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.small {
  width: calc(40% - 22px);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 1</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 1</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 2</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 3</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 4</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 2 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can re-arragne the div
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"c> I AM BIG 1</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 1</div>
   <div class="big"> I AM BIG 2</div>
    <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 2 </div>
    <div class="big"> I AM BIG 3</div>
     <div class="big"> I AM BIG 4</div>
</div>


or if you dont want to re-arrange the html structure then you can make use of order property in css.

ref: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Comment: You might be able to do that using the `grid-area`. Here is a very helpful guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: You can use Bootstrap framework to achieve your task. Why to write custom code if you already have something ready-made, you can use framework and can focus on your other dev tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with CSS grid layout:

- you can use `grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;` because you have 60% to 40% ratio of the `big` and `small` elements,
- row heights can be set using `grid-auto-rows: 100px`,
- margin between rows can be set using `grid-row-gap` property,
- now set the `big` to always occupy the first column using `grid-column: 1` and the `small` to always occupy the second.

See demo below for the configuration upto now:

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.big {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lime;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.small {
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 1</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 1</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 2</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 3</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 4</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 2 </div>
</div>
```

Now just add `grid-auto-flow: dense` to pull the orange blocks to the top - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr; /* two columns */
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* row height */
  grid-row-gap: 10px; /* gap between rows */
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* added */
}

.big {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lime;
  grid-column: 1; /* in first column */
}

.small {
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 2; /* in second column */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 1</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 1</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 2</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 3</div>
  <div class="big"> I AM BIG 4</div>
  <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That look nice and exactly what I need but if I have 3 sizes will be possible as well? I mean 3 blocks like 30% 40% and another 30%

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning on using flex I would suggest you break up your container into two columns which makes it easier to do this. This a test code I have done to achieve that. Hope it helps you.

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column mr-1">
    <div class="big-box">
      BOX 1
    </div>
    <div class="big-box">
      BOX 2
    </div>
    <div class="big-box">
      BOX 3
    </div>
    <div class="big-box">
      BOX 4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="small-box">
      BOX 5
    </div>
    <div class="small-box">
      BOX 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.big-box {
  background-color: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.small-box {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mr-1 {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/uvr0hzkw/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify this by changing the order of your `divs` as

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="big"> I AM BIG 1</div>
    <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 1</div>
    <div class="big"> I AM BIG 2</div>
    <div class="small"> I AM SMALL 2 </div>
    <div class="big"> I AM BIG 3</div>
    <div class="big"> I AM BIG 4</div>  
</div>
```

[image]

Hope this is what you've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
border: 1px solid red;
padding: 5px;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
.left{
width:59.8%; 
}
.right{
width:39.8%;
position:relative;
display:block;
}
.right .orange-block:last-child{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  bottom:0;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
.lime-block,.orange-block{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height:80px;
  padding:5px;
}
.lime-block:last-child,.orange-block:last-child{
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.lime-block{
  background:lime;
}
.orange-block{
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="left">
  <div class="lime-block">I AM BIG 1</div>
  <div class="lime-block">I AM BIG 2</div>
  <div class="lime-block">I AM BIG 3</div>
  <div class="lime-block">I AM BIG 4</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="orange-block">I AM SMALL 1</div>
  <div class="orange-block">I AM SMALL 2</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's a simple code as you want in flex based and also it support to do dynamic content.